# Удаление одинаковых слов из двух файлов

Tags: php

Вот есть такой скрипт, но очень долго работает. Как это можно ускорить?

```
<?php
$LOL = file('1.txt');
$BIG = file('2.txt');
$RES = array_diff ($LOL, $BIG);
file_put_contents('3.txt', implode('', $RES));
?>
```

Comment: Какой размер у файлов? Насколько долго работает скрипт? Приведите примеры содержания файлов. Слова в файлах как-то упорядочены?

Comment: В файлах массивы записаны, что ли?

Comment: @terantul, `file()` возвращает массив строк http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file.php